# How do I store symbolic links in a ZIP file using Perl?

Tags: perl, symlink

I'm using `Archive::Zip`, and I'd like to add symbolic links to an archive that I'm creating. Somehow I can't see how to do that.

It appears that when extracting a ZIP file, `Archive::Zip` does recognize contained symbolic links. But is there a write API?

Perhaps there's something that can be done by creating an `Archive::Zip::Member` and setting the (internal? external?) attributes? If so, I don't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

Poking around the source code, it seems the trick is to create a member object, and set the right attributes, like this:

```
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
my $member = $zip->addString( 'plain-file', 'symlink-pointing-to-plain-file' );
$member->{'externalFileAttributes'} = 0xA1FF0000;
```

I got this from the code that adds files and detects that it is a symlink. Let's hope there aren't any edge cases...